# Is it a good idea to use a virtual machine as an external facing code repository server

Tags: security, virtualization, virtual-machines

I've already asked this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1549164/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-a-virtual-machine-as-an-external-facing-code-repository) but it died out with no conclusive answer.

### Original question:

I've set up (installed git/configured certs (disabled password login)/synced repos) a debian box vm with a bridged adapter. Now it's running on Windows server 2016; inbound connections are blocked by an external firewall.

### Is it a good idea to add a firewall exception for the vm so that outsourcing teams can work on the repos directly?

Am I missing any security related stuff?

Answer (score 1):

My security rule of thumb: publish something when you want to available for everybody. In every other cases use one of VPN technologies.

Comment: Yes, I do want it to be made available to everybody but is a vm debian image more exploitable than a standalone machine? How "secure" is the VM container?

Comment: Do You mean everybody in the world? In this case not the vm is the bigest security problem. I recommend to always separate published services from internal LAN, that's call a DMZ (demilitarized zone). Naturally, this concern is true  for virtualization layer too. So I'd install a DMZ, a separated virtualization solution and install VM on that.